# Angular + DataTables: Options Not Working Correctly (bDestroy involved)

Tags: angularjs, datatable

**Set-Up:**

I'm using the jquery-datatables-rails gem.
I added this directive (http://jsfiddle.net/zdam/pb9ba/) from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/vM2DEMK_NMA and tweaked it to come up with this

```
myDirectives.directive('angularDataTable', ['$timeout', function(timer) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // apply DataTable options, use defaults if none specified by user
    var options = {};
    if (attrs.angularDataTable.length > 0) {
      options = scope.$eval(attrs.angularDataTable);
    } else {
      options = {
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bDestroy": false,
      };
    }
    // Tell the dataTables plugin what columns to use
    // We can either derive them from the dom, or use setup from the controller           
    var explicitColumns = [];

    var dataTableSet = function(){
      element.find('th').each(function(index, elem) {
        explicitColumns.push($(elem).text());
      });


      if (explicitColumns.length > 0) {
        options["aoColumns"] = explicitColumns;
      } else if (attrs.aoColumns) {
        options["aoColumns"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumns);
      }

      // aoColumnDefs is dataTables way of providing fine control over column config
      if (attrs.aoColumnDefs) {
        options["aoColumnDefs"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumnDefs);
      }

      // apply the plugin
      var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);
    };
    // watch for any changes to our data, rebuild the DataTable
    scope.$watch(attrs.aaData, function(value) {
      var completeData = scope.$eval(attrs.allData);
      var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);
      var val = value || null;
      if (val) {
        dataTable.fnClearTable();
        dataTable.fnAddData(scope.$eval(attrs.aaData));
        var table = document.getElementsByClassName("dataTable")[0];
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
          $(row).click(function(){
            window.location.hash = '#/dashboard/patients/' + completeData[i].patient_id;
          })
        };
      }
    });
    timer(dataTableSet);
  };
}]);
```

**Problem:**

When I set the options to include

```
bDestroy: true
```

then the other options I pass in aren't working. For example, if I say pagination: false I'll still have pagination in my table.

If I set bDestroy to false then the same thing happens where components like pagination aren't being reflected accurately, assuming in my $watch I no longer pass any options into

```
var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);
```

The only thing that seems to make the table acknowledge the different options I feed it, such as pagination, is if I change bDestroy to false and in the code directly above keep the argument of 'element.dataTable' as 'options' but then this alerts pops up.

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy
```

I see that it is referencing the fact I'm feeding an argument to 'element.dataTables' without bDestroy set to true, but changing that leads me back to my original problem.

Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the previous occur was occurring, but if I set bRetrieve to true rather than bDestroy to true the issue is solved. I made this change because I saw my options were being reflected in my initial table if I commented out all my options but pagination false, but the new table created after my data had been added was not reflecting my pagination false. Since bDestroy reinitializes a table and bRetrieve just retrieves the table and keeps the previous options I thought it might work, which it did. Based on this (http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options).

Anyway, if anyone has a good explanation as to the why behind this since I was passing in options before that were being ignored, I'll accept the answer. Just wanted to put this up in case someone ran into a similar issue :)